# Full sized images in RSS Feed

Tags: rss, images

On my WordPress site all my images from all posts are using a width of 630px (with a full width of 1280px). For obvious reasons on my site I only display the 630px version and the user can click on it to see the full size version. However, the same setup is not available via RSS.

I'm targeting an RSS reader that will display my post only on high-end smartphones screens with HD (720p) and FHD (1080p) resolution. You can imagine that the 630px images will not look too good. Is there an easy way to replace the 630px images with their full sized versions (1280px)?

Comment: Are these images just inline with the content or feature images on the post?

Comment: They are inline, inside each post - around 30-40 images in each post.